# Accessing the 3d model using c# script in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I am developing a software using c# (monodevelop) and unity3d. I am importing a 3d model as collada dae file. Scripts that I wrote must take into account geometry objects in dae file. I am writing some codes but I am new at coding stuff and I can not figure out how I can access geometric objects in dae file using c#. Any help would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said you are new with coding, I will start from the very Unity basics.

When you drag and drop your dae file from the project tab into the scene, you will have a GameObject inside the Hierarchy with the same name of dae file. That GameObject can be expanded like Windows Explorer with your all inner objects (they are all GameObjects as well).

To access any unique GameObject of your Hierarchy from C#, you do this: *GameObject.Find("desired-gameobject-name");*

You can also specify the path of your GameObject if its name is not unique:
*GameObject.Find("GameObject1/GameObject2/Etc");*

Most part of time when you want to do anything with a GameObject, you need to deal with Components. It's a very simple Unity concept. GameObject may have Components associated with them. The inspector tab shows all Components used by the selected GameObject.

Let's say you want to make a door invisible from your house dae model. You can use something like this:
*GameObject.Find("HouseModel/Door").GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;*

Now, if you want something more hardcore like getting vertices data, use the MeshFilter component:
*Vector3[] vertices = GameObject.Find("HouseModel/Door").GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertices;*
It will return an array of all vertices from this door.

I hope it gives you some direction.

Comment: hi @glauber, although this is an admirable answer, it is best to **just do not answer** questions that are simply looking for the most basic tutorials.  it produces an incredible clutter on this site.  I always simply leave a polite note to the OP, "basic unity tutorials are here ...".  (Unity offers excellent tutorials, both written and video) and then of course click to close the question.

Comment: it helped so much thank you for answer